# Running a Gunicorn instance on startup using a .service file (ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, service, gunicorn

I have a python flask server That I want to run on my VPS, this could be easily solved by installing Gunicorn, well I've done that, the next step will be to have it run on startup/after reboot

**Some context**

`/etc/systemd/system/FrenchNoodles-flask-gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve FrenchNoodle-flask
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/apps/FrenchNoodle-flask-venv
Environment="PATH=/root/apps/FrenchNoodle-flask-venv/FrenchNoodle-flask-venv/bin"
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/apps/FrenchNoodle-flask-venv/FrenchNoodle-flask-venv/bin --workers 3 --bind unix:FrenchNoodles-flask.sock wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**My file structure**

[image: File Structure]

**Inside** `/root/apps/FrenchNoodle-flask-venv/FrenchNoodle-flask`

[image: Inside FrenchNoodles-flask project file]

**Inside** `/root/apps/FrenchNoodle-flask-venv/FrenchNoodle-flask/wsgi.py`

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**Error**
After running `sudo systemctl status FrenchNoodles-flask-gunicorn.service`

```
● FrenchNoodles-flask-gunicorn.service - Gunicorn instance to serve FrenchNoodle-flask
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/FrenchNoodles-flask-gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-11-19 14:57:56 UTC; 11min ago
   Main PID: 8475 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Nov 19 14:57:56 FrenchNoodles-Droplet systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve FrenchNoodle-flask.
Nov 19 14:57:56 FrenchNoodles-Droplet systemd[8475]: FrenchNoodles-flask-gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Nov 19 14:57:56 FrenchNoodles-Droplet systemd[8475]: FrenchNoodles-flask-gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /root/apps/FrenchNoodle-flask-venv/FrenchNoodl>
Nov 19 14:57:56 FrenchNoodles-Droplet systemd[1]: FrenchNoodles-flask-gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Nov 19 14:57:56 FrenchNoodles-Droplet systemd[1]: FrenchNoodles-flask-gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) tutorial

**Edit**
I have changed the file structure to make cleaner, now the files are all in the root folder, and the venv file is also in that root folder

[image: New file structure]

Comment: `Failed to execute command: Permission denied` do the files have proper permissions on them to be executed?

Comment: @gold_cy I have no Idea

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to switch out the unix:socket into an IP:PORT